# How Can I Change the Y-axis labels to be shown as strings other than number in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, string, chart.js, chart.js2

I am creating a chart.js line graph with -y-axis values up to almost a million. and the values on the y axis are
0
100000
200000
300000
400000 and so on. This can be tiresome to read and I want to change it for those numbers to strings that say 100k 200k 300k while still maintaining the same value as before just showing different values on the page.
Is this possible?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use this example from their documentation, instead of returning a dollar sign + value return: (value/1000 + 'K')

```
options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a K in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return (Number.parseInt(value)/1000) + 'K';
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot but do you know how I can do the same thing to when it hovers. Because when I hover over it it still returns the full number.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific, as far as I know you dont get to see anything if you hover over the axes on the canvas

Comment: I mean when I hover over the line graph itself

Comment: Can de the same for the ticks with a custom callback, you have to use the label callback and implement it in a same way as you did with the ticks https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks

Comment: Have any way to do the same thing without callback function? If answer is not please tell me why?

Comment: Yes, you have 2 options. Deliver your data pre transformed as strings to chartjs with the k at the end or use a custom tooltip. The only other way to get the behaviour from the default tooltip without using callback or strings as values is adjusting the lib tooltip logic and compiling your own version of it